# Rsync Push files from linux to windoes. ssh issue - connection refused

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sftp, rsync

For some reason I want to run a script to move files from Linux machine to Windows. 
I have installed cwRsync on my windows machine and able to connect to linux machine.

When i execute following command:

```
rsync -e "ssh -l "piyush"" -Wgovz --timeout 120 --delay-updates --remove-sent-files /usr/local/src/piyush/sync/* "piyush@10.0.0.60:/cygdrive/d/temp"
```

Where 10.0.0.60 is my widows machine and I am running above command on Linux - CentOS 5.5.

After running command I get following error message:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.60 port 22: Connection refused
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(463) [sender=2.6.8]
[root@localhost sync]# ssh uniken@10.0.0.60
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.60 port 22: Connection refused
```

I have modified my firewall settings on widows to allow all ports. 
I think this issue is due to SSH Daemon not present on my windows machine. 
So I tried installing OpenSSH on my machine and running ssh-agent but didn't helped.

I tried similar command to run on my widows machine to pull files from Linux and its working fine. For some reason I want command for Linux machine so that I can embed it in a shell script.

Can you suggest me if I am missing anything.

---

I am already having cwRsync installed on my widows and running it in daemon mode using --damemon option. 
And I am able to login using ssh from windows machine to linux machine.

When I issue bellow command, it just blocks for 120 seconds (timeout I specified in command) and exits saying there is timeout.

```
rsync -e "ssh -l piyush" -Wgovz --timeout 120 --delay-updates --remove-sent-files /usr/local/src/piyush/sync/* "piyush@10.0.0.60:/cygdrive/d/temp"
```

After starting rsync on widows, I checked, rsyc is running. And widows firewall setting are set to minimal, and on Linux machine stopped iptables service so that port 873 (default rsync port) is not blocked.

What can be the possible reason that Linux machine is not able to connect to rsync-daemon on windows machine?

Comment: //am able to login using ssh from windows machine to linux machine.
You should try the reverse. login to windows machine from linux to make sure you have ssh daemon running on windows.

Comment: I tried that also and SSH is working fine both ways.  

Note: I am using Windows 7 and Linux Centos 5.5

Comment: I even tried by omitting ssh as suggested bellow by 3molo, but still its not working. It asks for password to authenticate and then just blocks. 
In cwrsyn log I can see that rsync has started listening on port 873.

Answer (score 1):

Piyush, rsync in daemon mode supports connectivity over the rsync protocol, rather than only over ssh protocol. 
Modify:

```
rsync -e "ssh -l piyush" -Wgovz --timeout 120 --delay-updates --remove-sent-files /usr/local/src/piyush/sync/* "piyush@10.0.0.60:/cygdrive/d/temp"
```

to:

```
rsync -Wgovz --timeout 120 --delay-updates --remove-sent-files /usr/local/src/piyush/sync/* rsync://piyush@10.0.0.60:/cygdrive/d/temp
```

Answer (score 0):

cwRsync:

> Rsync normally uses ssh for communication. It requires no special privileges for installation. **You must, however, have a working ssh system.**

I assume you don't have it. I can recommend cygwin (do `ssh-host-config` after installation). However, this is frequently not (perceived as) easy.

You can also opt to use `rsync` daemon.

1. write an [rsyncd.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf)
2. run rsync daemon (consult cwRsync documentation, or just manually start `rsync --daemon` for now) on the windows machine
3. instead of `piyush@10.0.0.60:/some/real/path` use e.g. `piyush@10.0.0.60::somemodule/subpath/file.txt`

some background: http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650

Comment: "Alternatively, rsync can run in `daemon' mode, listening on a socket. This is generally used for public file distribution, although authentication and access control are available. Cygwin is a Linux-like environment for Windows. It consists of a DLL (cygwin1.dll), which emulates substantial Linux API functionality, and a collection of tools." // http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650